# indentation and syntax highlighting stops working randomly

Tags: indentation, syntax-highlighting, display, error, text

Every now and when emacs indentation and syntax highlighting stops working. This seems to affect all modes that I'm using (primarily `org-mode`,`ess-mode` and `emacs-lisp-mode`), and manifests itself in changes in the text not being displayed properly, such as when adding emphases in org-mode (bold, italic underline), writing comments on a newline (text is written in the normal face), adding headers/sections in org-mode (indentation and highlighting is not considered) or writing strings in `ess-mode`/`emacs-lisp-mode`. In all these situations, text is just displayed in the default face.

If I reload the file I'm working on (or restart `org-mode`), syntax highlighting and indentation will be applied to the text sections that didn't have it before, but text I write from that point onwards is still not properly formated (just as before, indentation and syntax highlighting is ignored). Similarly calling `font-lock-update` updates the syntax highlighting of already existing text, but does not correct org-mode indentation or correctly displays text I'm writing from that point onwards.

This happens to me rarely, maybe a once every couple months (and I'm using emacs almost all day every day), but when it does, I have to restart emacs, after which things work perfectly again (restarting is still a hassle tho). There are no error messages, so I don't know what is causing this phenomenon. I also can't think of a way to debug this. Any ideas how I can find out what's going on?

Comment: The strange thing is that the two (indentation and syntax highlighting) are independent of each other AFAIK, so having both of them go at the same time is ... strange. One thing that you can do when that happens is to check the minor modes of the buffer with `C-h m`. The minor modes appear on the first line of the `*Help*` buffer. They should include `Font-lock` in particular. The other thing that you can do is to check the bindings with `C-h c` or `C-h k` for whatever key(s) you use for indentation when things are working and then repeat when things are broken and compare the two. Good luck!